# Screen doesn't turn off

Tags: hdmi, screen

Is there a way for the hdmi output to completely turn off. When I leave my pi idle the screen turns black but the screen stays on and never turns off. The monitor turns to off/idle with other computers but it doesn't with the pi, just turns black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://begunje.dyndns.org/archives/2012/08/21/fixing_broken_raspberry_pi_hdmi_dpms_monitor_power_saving/index.html).

According to the author, the kernel framebuffer driver does not have complete power management support.  Perhaps future versions of the Raspbian kernel will contain a fix.  Until then, the author provides a workaround script that polls to see whether the screen should be off or on and runs `tvservice --off` or `tvservice --preferred` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try adding the line `hdmi_blanking=1` to /boot/config.txt. It automatically turns off the monitor or TV when the pi blanks the screen. It's not yet implemented on the RPi4, although it works on all previous generations of Raspberry Pis. [Video Options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

EDIT: It has long been implemented on the Raspberry Pi 4. I just forgot that this comment was out there. Also, there's a setting for screen blanking in the GUI config app and possibly the CLI one. I think that controls the blanking only, and not whether the screen physically turns off. You may still need the above flag for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your Linux distribution. Tv screen should turn off when raspberry will stop send signal.

On the other hand I discover that when I turn on screen after run pi it does not connect to each other. This issue looks like firmware stuff and there is no solution fot this now.

Answer (score 1):

In current firmware you can to turn the monitor off and on with the folowing:

OFF: `sudo vcgencmd display_power 0`

ON: `sudo vcgencmd display_power 1`

It does not risk changing resolution, and there is no need for fbset, chvt, xrefresh, or restarting your GLES and OMX overlays afterwards.

I've tested it on my Raspberry Pi 3